# Alternative to TrueCrypt?

Tags: fedora, truecrypt, software-rec

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is distributed on a non-free license, and is therefore [not included in the Fedora repos](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Forbidden_items#TrueCrypt).

What alternatives would you suggest?

Comment: Does the license really matter that much? They offer it for free :/ just add their repo.

Comment: Well I heard that some if it is kind of secretly veiled from the public, as if they want to keep a backdoor open? I don't know, I didn't dive too much into that stuff.

Comment: I highly doubt that! It is open source, anyone can see the source code if they wish.

Comment: @polemon: That's a very nice tin-foil hat you have, but you shouldn't rely on hearsay. Note that TC has been open-source for some time (and the full code has been reviewed). The problem that most distros have is that the [license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt#Licensing) is not compatible with theirs. See e.g. this for Tom Callaway's (of Red Hat) take on it: http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/distributions/2008-October/000276.html

Comment: Here is [the TrueCrypt license](http://www.truecrypt.org/legal/license), and it looks more copyleft than the BSD license but more copyright than the GPL (modifications *are* permitted, and you *have* to distribute the source).  Also, that TrueCrypt information was added three years ago to that Wiki site (and their original recommendation was to use [RealCrypt](http://wiki.mandriva.com/en/RealCrypt) instead, but there's no point - just use TrueCrypt, it's the best encryption software I've ever used TBH).

Comment: @Piskvor: It isn't so much a tin-foil hat, as simply I took a look at the Linux integration, ans simply didn't like it. Compared to LUKS,TrueCrypt lacks in system integration. Also, TrueCrypt doesn't handle logical volume groups so well...

Comment: @polemon: That is something completely, *completely* different from what you're claiming in your previous comment: "I heard that some if it is kind of secretly veiled from the public, as if they want to keep a backdoor open? -polemon Aug 31 at 11:11" - that is a textbook example of hearsay-fuelled excessive paranoia, a.k.a. "tin-foil hat mode". I don't see how "TC doesn't integrate well with Linux" is equivalent to "TC is untrustworthy as it could contain backdoors".

Comment: @Piskvor, I'll be very interested by a link about that full code review because I tried to find one last year without luck, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LUKS](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Implementing_LUKS_Disk_Encryption) is probably the most common method for encrypting whole filesystems.

For single directories (e.g. ~/Private), eCryptFS is good.

Comment: What would you suggest when encrypting USB flash drives, or SD cards?

Comment: LUKS is compatible with FreeOTFE, if you need a cross-platform tool.

Comment: Well, I'm very happy with how well LUKS is integrated into the system. Cross-platform capabilities are nice to have, but FreeOTFE isn't a too great program...